# Image does not appear Apex Oracle

Tags: html, image, oracle-apex

Good morning all,

I'm new to Apex and want to post articles with images.

I follow this tutorial on Youtube (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jk8iwlTTong), everything works because it is very explicit but the problem is when displaying the image because I have this result (after deactivating special characters in the security tab):

[image]

Here are all the configurations and the request I made to display it but there I really can't do it.

The sql request :

```
select ID,
  TITRE "CARD_TITLE",
  AUTEUR "CARD_SUBTITLE",
  DESCRIPTION "CARD_SUBTEXT",
  DECODE(TO_CHAR(nvl(dbms_lob.getlength(PHOTO),0)), '0', null, 
  '<img alt="'||apex_escape.html_attribute(PHOTO_FILENAME)||'"title="'||apex_escape.html_attribute(PHOTO_FILENAME)
    ||'" style="border: 4px solid #CCC; -moz-border-radius: 4px; -webkit-border-radius: 4px;" '
     ||'src="'||apex_util.get_blob_file_src('P13_PHOTO', ID)||'" height="150" width="200" />')"CARD_TEXT"
  from ARTICLES
```

My table articles (posts) :

[image]

My attribute "Card Subtext" :

[image]

Indeed there is marked "Plain Text" except that if I select "Display Image" I must choose the table and the column to display while it must be made directly from the request (maybe my error comes from there but I don't think).

By the way, I also can't see where the image was downloaded from the form. Maybe the error comes from here.

Here is my form:

[image]

Thank you in advance for your help, I think I have all detailed.

Have a great day

Comment: Rewatch the video from 4:09 - 4:37. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jk8iwlTTong&t=4m9s Did you do that part?

Comment: Hello, indeed you are right I do not have the 'Display As' because I am with a more recent version. I don't think that's the problem, look at the post it has changed since yesterday;) Do you have other ideas?

Answer (score 3):

Go to CARD_SUBTEXT column  attribute, then go to SECURITY turn off 'Escape special characters'

[click to see the image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vjp8x.png)

Comment: Hello, thank you very much for your answer which helped me a lot. I just made the change and indeed there is a change. But I have the impression that the image does not load. (I modified my post you can see the modifications above). Do you know where are stored the images that have entered thanks to the form? Because I do not have the impression that they are charged. Thanks again, happy holidays

Comment: on the last line of the query  --->>||'src="'||apex_util.get_blob_file_src('P13_PHOTO_FILENAME', ROWID)|| ---- >> change -->   P13_PHOTO_FILENAME --> to -->  P13_PHOTO

Comment: thank you for your answer, I just changed, there is no change. Image does not appear

Comment: Also  in the same line change ROWID to ID  --    the last line will be like this --- > ||'src="'||apex_util.get_blob_file_src('P13_PHOTO', ID)||'" height="150" width="200" />')"CARD_SUBTEXT"

Comment: hi Thank you for your message, it still does not work. I updated my question above to what it should look like but the picture does not appear